# Why the variable in lambda is not able to call the function

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

This is the class.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string strName = "ABC";

class BlueOut
{
public:
    void printName() { std::cout << strName << std::endl; }

};
```

Now i create a object of this class

```
 BlueOut blueout;
```

And i call the function printName() of the object in lambda

```
auto a = [&]() { blueout.printName(); };
```

But the function does not gets executed.

Comment: Are you calling the lambda like `a();`?

Comment: Voting to close due to no MCVE, but probably you just didn't call the lambda.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this line,

```
auto a = [&]() { blueout.printName(); };
```

the part `[&]() { blueout.printName(); }` is called a lambda expression. You bind it to some variable `a`. Now you have a function object `a` created by a lambda expression. In order to see the effect, this has to be invoked:

```
a();
```